# Updating QGIS: is it possible to save customizations like personal settings, hotkeys, styles, sandard symbols, toolbars?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, symbology, qgis-customization

I want to update QGIS from 3.16 tot 3.22 for me and my co-workers.

Some people have put effort into getting all their settings right (customizations: toolbar placements, symbology and symbology label settings, colour bars, startup, buttons, hotkeys, plug-ins, fonts in layout or labels, comma/point settings...). I know you can export some settings, but does this work between different versions of QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the directory you want to keep from `users/.../AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles` and paste it in the new `profiles` directory of your fresh QGIS install. I hope it saves all the settings you said.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, settings are preserved during an update. At least if the update is made on top of the previous install, for instance using OSGeo4W.

There are exceptions for things that have changed between versions of course. And I’m not sure what a 2.x to 3.x upgrade would break, but I’ve updated with every 3.x.y point release since 3.4 and haven’t had any problems.